# `exit` event in node.js behaves different than in the manual

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, listener, shutdown-hook

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

> Listener functions must only perform synchronous operations. The
>   Node.js process will exit immediately after calling the 'exit' event
>   listeners causing any additional work still queued in the event loop
>   to be abandoned. In the following example, for instance, the timeout
>   will never occur:

```
process.on('exit', (code) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('This will not run');
  }, 0);
});
```

Now I have this in my main.js:

```
if (errors) {
    process.exitCode = 1;
}
process.emit("exit");
```

In a logger that has shutdown listeners etc I have a mongo connection and the following:

```
    process.on("exit", (code) => {
        if (this.status.finishedAt === null) {
            this.status.currentState = StatusUpdater.STATE_STOPPED;
            this.status.finishedAt = new Date();
            this.persistStatus()
            .then(() => {
                this.mongoDb.close().then(() => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log('byebye');
                        process.exit(code);
                    }, 5000);
                });
            })
            .catch(this.noMongoConnection);
        }
    });
```

The output is: `byebye` **after 5 seconds**.

Now I am confused. Obviously I can do asyncronous operations after the `exit` event is triggered. The manual says this is not possible.

What is right and what is wrong?

Comment: Calling `process.exit(code);` inside the `exit` event handler is very weird. I wonder whether this will actually trigger all your handlers twice.

Comment: @Bergi it does, so I check for the `finishedAt` is not undefined. Also when you trigger a `SIGINT`, the `exit` event is also called afterwards.

Comment: @Bergi Do you have an idea for a shutdown handler other than how I did it? The only downside of my solution is that when there is another exit listener and has a chance not to be executed when I do the `process.exit()` before that other listener.

Comment: Admittedly I have no idea what the best practice is, but I would at least use a different event name for the asynchronous exit handlers. And I would not call `process.exit(1)` from the mongodb handler, but from the place where I'd fire the shutdown event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are manually emitting an event with the name `exit`, which does not cause any special behaviour by itself. Only if you used [`process.exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) as in

```
if (errors)
    process.exit(1);
```

it would have the effects described in the documentation.

Comment: The difference between calling `.exit()` and emitting the `exit` event should be clearer in the docs but your answer helps to understand it's not the same.